# What is the Google version of Yahoo's Data tables?

Tags: google, api, yahoo

I find Yahoo! Data tables very useful. You can access them using YQL (Yahoo query language) to retrieve information such as stock markets, currency rates, etc. See http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/ for more information.

I was wondering, though, whether Google has anything similar?

Answer (score 1):

You can extract info from any public web page using Google Docs Spreadsheet function [ImportXML](https://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=155184).

*ImportXML lets you get information from filetypes such as xml, html, csv, tsv, as well as RSS and Atom feeds*

Once you have the extracted info in a Google Docs Spreadsheet, you can choose to [embed it within a web page](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55244).

Answer (score 0):

While there isn't anything that's a direct equivalent of Yahoo's Open Data Tables, Google does have two products that serve a similar purpose:

### Google Fusion Tables

http://www.google.com/fusiontables/

> The purpose of this app is exactly what open data people should be
>   looking for. It’s about defining data tables (hence the name), filling
>   them up with data, maintain the data collaboratively,  discuss it,
>   visualize it and “merge” it with other open data tables. SQL users,
>   think JOIN.
>
> ...
>
> Naturally, there is an API for read and write access to Fusion Tables.
>   People who know SQL will likely feel comfortable with that, since one
>   basically interacts with fusion tables via a subset of SQL, issued via
>   REST web service queries.

### Google Public Data Explorer

http://www.google.com/publicdata/home

> Public Data Explorer has been around as  labs product for a while,
>   allowing users to explore a couple of datasets prepared by Google.
>   But, just recently, it has been announced in the Official Google Blog
>   that Public Data Explorer is now open to user submissions. If you’re
>   interested, the Nieman Lab blog has additional insights about the new
>   launch.
>
> For that purpose, a new data exchange format called Dataset Publishing
>   Language (DSPL) has been released.
>
> DSPL is worth a closer look, since it tackles many of the problems
>   which have already been mentioned above: Lack of schema, lack of
>   metadata, lack of self-descriptiveness and being limited two low
>   dimensionality. In DSPL, the meta information about the dataset is
>   described in an XML file. This file contains general information and
>   describes “concepts”. For example, the DSPL package about european
>   unemployment data (available from the code site) defines – among
>   others – a concept of countries and of country_groups. It also
>   contains relationship information telling us that country_groups
>   consist of countries. These concepts are then linked to data tables
>   which are provided as separate CSV files.

Reference: [Google’s Open Data Toolkit Mess/Wealth](http://www.sendung.de/2011-02-26/google-open-data-toolkit-mess-wealth/)